# How can I use a Git repository for multiple projects in Eclipse, each with a different remote GitHub repo

Tags: eclipse, git, github

There were tutorials on how to use one Eclipse Git repo for multiple project: https://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/workflow-create-multi-project-repositories-egit/

And how to push to multiple remote repos: http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2013/10/push-multiple-remote-git-repositories-using-1-eclipse-operation-killing-2-birds-1-stone/

However, as the name indicates, I want to use only one git repository in Eclipse to include multiple projects, **each with a different GitHub repo.**

I want each project has a different GitHub repo, when pushing a project, it should only be pushed to its own GitHub repo.

Comment: I'm not sure if Eclipse has some black magic that can make this work, but in general anything in a single repository locally will be in a single repository remotely.

Comment: **Why** do you want a single local repository? I don't see the point of doing all this.

Comment: @Zeeker Because, I want less non-code-relevant folders and files in my workspace.

Comment: The advantage being? As long as Eclipse handles your git relevant files properly you don't have to take a second look at those files.

Comment: Furthermore I would consider the version control history of a project as code-relevant.